# Unit test project not building from build server

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

My VS2010 solution has a test project in it.  The unit tests themselves reference the following namespace:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
```

which is accessed via the following assembly on my PC:

```
Assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\
    PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
```

When I build the solution on my PC I have no issues; the tests will build and run okay.

We have an intranet page which we can use to kick off builds on a build server.  When I build via this page, the build fails with the following errors:

```
Generator.cs(3,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' 
does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly
reference?)
```

The obvious problem would be that the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll` mentioned above is not present on the build server.  I thought this was would be installed with VS2010, and since the projects in my solution build .NET 4.0 targets, I would expect this to be installed on the build server.

What is the easiest way to resolve this?  The build server is out of my jurisdiction and I don't particular want to log a job to get new libraries installed on to it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The .UnitTestFramework.dll sits in C:\Program Files... folder and you have a reference to it.

1. Create directory under your source control eg. Source/Binaries
2. Copy the said dll into Source/Binaries
3. Remove the reference to .UnitTestFramework.dll from your unit test assembly
4. Add the reference to .UnitTestFramework.dll to your unit test assembly but this time select the dll that is now under Source/Binaries

After that you can checkin your changes (make sure the Source/Binaries folder is checked in) and build the solution. When build server builds the solution it should get the dll from the source control.

Comment: Wouldn't there be licensing issues with those dlls when you e.g. have your project as an open source project on e.g. Github?

Comment: Just to answer my own comment: Yes, there will be licensing issues - this would not be allowed: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/32384366-b668-4f18-99eb-9c67f7eef233/redistributing-microsoftvisualstudioqualitytoolsunittestframeworkdll

Comment: I did what the answer suggests. it works for my development PC (with VS) and our CI server (without VS). I would rather have the DLL pulled by NuGet, but I can't get that to work.

Answer (score 13):

The specific answer for me and a Visual Studio 2010 solution was:

1. Install "Test Agent 2010" from [Visual Studio Agents 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1334)
2. Restart Windows
3. Install [Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)
4. Restart Windows
5. Ensure the projects References are updated to point at "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework" "10.1.0.0" and not "10.0.0.0".

Comment: Note that Visual Studio Agents 2015 installs framework 4.6.1 if your server doesn't already have it

Comment: To save someone else some time, the current version of the agents can be downloaded from https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/?q=agents