# Minimum software requirements to build VS2013 ASP.NET MVC Web Application in TeamCity 8.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, teamcity

I'm setting up TeamCity 8.1 in an empty Windows 7 machine. What are the minimal software requirements in order to build a ASP.NET MVC Web Application created in Visual Studio 2013?

I will be using both Github and Subversion as source version control system (VCS).

On my first try there was no problems connecting to the VCS's. But I immediately started to get build errors, starting with

Unmet requirements: MSBuildTools12.0_x86_Path exists.

This is not so much a question since I'm answering it myself. I wanted to list the error messages I got in the process and how I solved them. I'm hoping this will help someone else in the same situation.

Comment: I initially got some downvotes for my question probably because it wasnt clear that I was planning on answering it myself and I had put all the effort in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After installing TeamCity 8.1 this is the errors I encountered trying to build an ASP.NET MVC Web Application and how I solved them:

**The first error**

```
Unmet requirements: MSBuildTools12.0_x86_Path exists
```

- This was solved with Microsoft Build Tools 2013
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760
- You can read more about it here 
  [Team city unmet requirement: MSBuildTools12.0_x86_Path exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20008861/team-city-unmet-requirement-msbuildtools12-0-x86-path-exists)

**The second error**

```
error MSB4019: 
The imported project 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found.
```

- You can find a description of the problem here
  [MSBuild in TeamCity of Visual Studio 2012 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419610/msbuild-in-teamcity-of-visual-studio-2012-solution)

  - The right folders for VS2013 are
  - C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web
  - C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\WebApplications

**The third error**

Occurs if you don't copy the package folder to your VCS. Then you need to restore the nuget packages before you build.

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'
```

- You can read more about it here 
  http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/08/nuget-package-restore-with-teamcity/

**Fourth problem** 
Happens if you have a test project with references to dll's that are not in the TeamCity server.

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'
```

- You can read more about it here
  [Unit test project not building from build server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921064/unit-test-project-not-building-from-build-server)
- I installed Agents for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40750 and it solved some problems